# Ruby: Unexpected behavior of alias_method when accessing an object

Tags: ruby

In Ruby you can redefine methods several ways. One is to open up the eigenclass, or singleton class, and another is to use `instance_eval`. However, `alias_method` is only available on the eigenclass. Why is that, or is there a way to use it with `instance_eval` ?

```
class << ENV
  # works
  alias_method :original_brackets, :[]

  # works
  def [](name)
    # ...
  end
end

ENV.instance_eval do
  # raises NoMethodError
  alias_method :original_brackets, :[]

  # works
  def [](name)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`alias_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) is part of `Module` class.  Inside the block to `instance_eval`, `self` is `ENV` object, and does not have access to `Module` methods.

```
ENV.instance_eval do
  p self.class
end
#=> Object
```

---

Typically, you can alias a method in `instance_eval` using below technique:

```
class Foo
    def bar
    end
end

p Foo.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:bar] 

Foo.new.instance_eval do 
    self.class.send :alias_method, :bar_orig, :bar  
end

p Foo.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:bar, :bar_orig]
```

In above case `send` has to be used as `alias_method` is private method and not accessible outside the class/module definition.

---

However, `ENV` is not instance of any special-purpose class (such as `Foo`) - instead, it is an instance of `Object` class with lot of singleton methods added to it.  Hence, above technique will not work, instead you have to do add aliases using `singleton` class of `ENV` object.

Here is how it can be done:

```
ENV.instance_eval do

  singleton_class.send :alias_method, :original_brackets, :[] rescue p "oops"

  def [](name)
  end

end
```

Or alternatively:

```
ENV.instance_eval do
  class << self
    alias_method :original_brackets, :[] 
  end

  def [](name)
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting. That makes sense. So how could I find that method on ENV? I tried ENV.singleton_methods and ENV.singleton_class.methods but neither returned :alias_method.

Comment: Try ENV.class.instance_methods

Comment: Same as singleton class. `ENV.class.methods.sort == ENV.singleton_class.methods.sort #=> true`